# I'm trying to create a websocket connection using spring boot and I want to call it using Postman socket.io

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-websocket

below is the spring boot websocket configuration

```
package com.testcode.booking.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/assignee/counter");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/queue/scanner");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/scanner-websocket");
    }
}
```

and this is the controller I'm trying to reach from Postman and send a response

```
package com.testcode.booking.controller.scanner;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.http.WebSocket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Base64;

@Controller
public class ApplicationScannerController {

    @MessageMapping("/dashboard")
    @SendTo("/assignee/counter/listener")
    public String assigneeApplicationToCounter() {
        return "test response";
    }

    @GetMapping("/scanner-websocket-shakeHand")
    public ResponseEntity<String> scannerWebSocketShakeHand() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String token = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("scanner-websocket-shakeHand".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.set("Upgrade", "websocket");
        headers.set("Connection", "Upgrade");
        headers.set("Sec-WebSocket-Key", token);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body("Response Body");
    }
}
```

when I try to connect to the WebSocket, I got this error: **Could not connect to ws://localhost:8084/scanner-websocket**
[image: Postman WebSocket Request]

What is wrong with the code or the configuration that I did so I couldn't connect to the WebSocket, and how can I send a message from Postman and receive a message from the controller to Postman like a response message?

Thanks in advance